# How to make a better self-closing toolbar button that always works?

Tags: gui-construction, options, button, user-interface, docked-cell

My `DockedCells`toolbar has a self-closing button that sometimes decides to permanently stop working on that particular notebook. closing and reopening file always loads all previous toolbar even when restarting kernel or frontend which is bad enough for the end user but even worse for the developer who then must copy all code to a new notebook to evaluate his edits.

The following function pulled out from the last button is the only way i know to close a docked cell from a button within the docked cell. A quick look reveals a few problems. It doesnt just target my toolbar. It removes all custom toolbars even those useless native ones.

```
Function[Null, 
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> Inherited, 
  TaggingRules -> Inherited, CellContext -> Inherited]]
```

The following is a greatly trimmed version of my toolbar given to provide a more complete picture of how i use it.`

```
toolbar[cellbg_ : RGBColor[.8, .85, 1, 1]] := Block[{},
   
   cellbuttons = Row[{
      Button["go to top", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookStart"]],
      Button["go to bottom", 
       FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookEnd"]],
      Button["close toolbar", 
       Function[Null, 
        SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> Inherited, 
         TaggingRules -> Inherited, CellContext -> Inherited]]]
      }];
   
   Echo[cellbuttons];
   
   SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    DockedCells -> Cell[
       BoxData[ToBoxes[cellbuttons]],
       "DockedCell",
       Background -> cellbg,
       CellMargins -> 0, 
       CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {2, 2}},
       CellFrameMargins -> {{20, 0}, {2, 2}}
       ];
    
    ]];

toolbar[];
```

**My questions are...**

1.how can i rewrite the function so that it only targets my toolbar preferably by identifying it with cell tags.

2. resetting options isn't very reliable. why isn't possible to just delete the offending code like we do with everything else in life?
   there has to be a better way.

Note: I could not get the trimmed down code to install (this explains the echo) but that is not the important part. what i really need is how to make the close function in the button more reliable.

Comment: You can selectively delete docked cells using `DeleteCases` with a suitable pattern or similar. I'd also suggest to consider adding your toolbar using `AppendTo[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],DockedCells],…]`. And regarding the issue with removing the cells: Can you check the settings for `DockedCells` for `$FrontEndSession` and `$FrontEnd`? I've sometimes had it happen that option values made their way "upwards" in the inheritance chain

Comment: @LukasLang thank you for your suggestions, ill give it a try.

Comment: @LukasLang thank you `AppendTo `worked! here is what replaced `SetOptions`.  AppendTo[
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells],
  Cell[
   BoxData[ToBoxes[nbtaskmategrid]],
   "DockedCell",
   Background -> cellbg,
   CellMargins -> 0,
   CellFrame -> frame,
   CellFrameMargins -> marg,
   CellFrameColor -> coalt
   ]];`

Comment: @LukasLang   finally got around to trying out selectively c;losing docked by their unique properties, The problem is I first need to tocate docked which `Cells` and `NotebookFind` cannot seem to do. More details here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272033/cannot-find-dockedcells-with-cells-or-notebookfind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]` instead of manipulating the `DockedCells` option:

```
toolbar[] := 
  With[{cellbuttons = 
     Row[{Button["go to top", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookStart"]], 
       Button["go to bottom", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookEnd"]], 
       Button["close toolbar", NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]]}]},
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> Inherited];
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    DockedCells -> {Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[cellbuttons]], "DockedCell"]}]];

toolbar[];
```

The first `SetOptions` is needed, because after `NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]` the value of the `DockedCells` option isn't changed, and setting it again to the same value has no effect (the deleted docked cell isn't restored).

Since `NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]` [doesn't change the value of the `DockedCells` option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272033/cannot-find-dockedcells-with-cells-or-notebookfind/272038#comment679459_272033), the removed toolbar will be restored after saving and reopening the Notebook. In order to remove the toolbar completely, one should remove it from `DockedCells`. Here is one possible implementation (it is assumed that docked cells cannot have the same contents):

```
toolbar[] := 
  Block[{cellbuttons = 
     Row[{Button["go to top", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookStart"]], 
       Button["go to bottom", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookEnd"]], 
       Button["close toolbar", 
        SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
         DockedCells -> 
          DeleteCases[Flatten[{CurrentValue[DockedCells]}], 
           Cell[First@NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]], __]]]]}]}, 
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    DockedCells -> {Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[cellbuttons]], "DockedCell"]}]];

toolbar[];
```

With this implementation, after clicking the "close toolbar" button,  `CurrentValue[DockedCells]` will return empty list `{}` if there was only one docked cell. This implementation is based on the assumption that `NotebookRead` returns the same for the first argument of `Cell` as it is specified in the value of `DockedCells` option. I'm not sure however that this assumption always holds, hence it is possible that this method fails in some rare cases which normally should not appear in practice. At the same time, the method via `NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]` will always work as expected. These two methods can be used simultaneously.

And here is a robust implementation based on [the official resource submission template](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/Unnamed-Function.nb):

```
toolbar[] := 
  With[{boxID = CreateUUID[], 
    pol = Polygon /@ {RotationTransform[Pi/4]@#, 
         RotationTransform[3 Pi/4]@#} &@{{-5, -1}, {-5, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, -1}}}, 
   With[{cellbuttons = 
      Grid[{{Button["go to top", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookStart"]], 
         Button["go to bottom", FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollNotebookEnd"]], 
         MouseAppearance[
          Button[MouseAppearance[
            PaneSelector[{False -> 
               Graphics[{GrayLevel[64/85], pol}, ImageSize -> 18, PlotRange -> 7], 
              True -> Graphics[{GrayLevel[128/255], pol}, ImageSize -> 18, 
                PlotRange -> 7]}, Dynamic[CurrentValue["MouseOver"]]], "LinkHand"], 
           CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] = 
            DeleteCases[Flatten[{CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells]}], 
             c_Cell /; ! FreeQ[c, boxID]], BoxID -> boxID, Appearance -> None], 
          "LinkHand"]}}]},
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] = 
     Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[cellbuttons]], "DockedCell"]]];

toolbar[];
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that it uses undocumented option `BoxID` to find the current docked cell.