# Cannot find DockedCells with Cells or NotebookFind

Tags: notebooks, functional-style, cells, user-interface, docked-cell

**Request 1:** *A workaround for `Cells` or `NotebookFind` needs to be found for locating and returning the `CellObject`-s of `DockedCells` with identifying cell properties like `CellID` or `CellTags`. Someone out there knows what to do. If you know of a way no matter how hackey please help.*

**Request 2:** *If you believe this is a bug with `Cells` or `NotebookFind` or should be considered one or is missing expected functionality, please alert me and I will happily submit a bug report or a request for feature enhancement to the **Wolf***

For plenitude I am coding a `DockedCells` toolbar remover which defaults to the nuclear option (removes all docked) but can selectively only remove single docked when given an identifying  property such as `CellTags` or `CellID`. The code is irrelevant but given in case you need it to clean up after testing your solutions to this.`

```
ClearAll[RemoveDocked]
RemoveDocked[spec_ : "Nuclear", prop_ : CellTags] := Module[{},
   (* nucLear option removes all docked *)
   If[(MatchQ[spec, All] || 
      StringMatchQ[spec, "nuclear" | "nuke", 
       IgnoreCase -> True]), (SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
      DockedCells -> Inherited]; Return[])];
   (* here is where code for removing individual docked would be placed *)
   Echo[spec, "spec \[RightTeeArrow]"];
   ];
```

Below are the sample `DockedCells` toolbars I coded to test my `CellObject` locators, which by the way work fine on `Input` cells but return empty list `{}`  for `Cells` and `$Failed` for`NotebookFind`.

```
ClearAll[ops, bops, txt, but, nuk]
ops = Sequence[FontSize -> 16, FontColor -> White, 
   FontFamily -> "Courier New", Background -> Darker@Darker@Blue, 
   CellFrameMargins -> 7, ShowCellTags -> False];
bops[col_ : Black, bg_ : None] := 
  Sequence[BaseStyle -> {12, col, Bold}, Background -> bg];
txt = Cell[
   "This is only plain text. No boxes were harmed in making this.", 
   "DockedCell", ops, CellID -> 111, CellTags -> "txt"];
but = Cell[
  BoxData[ToBoxes[
    Row[{"Manually save your work or turn on autosave. ", 
      Button["NB Save", NotebookSave[], bops[]], " ", 
      Button["NB AutoSave", 
       SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True], 
       bops[]]}]]], ops, CellID -> 222, CellTags -> "but"];
nuk = 
 Cell[BoxData[
   ToBoxes[Row[{Style["Exercise Nuclear Option: ", Bold, Italic], 
      "the world will never be the same again. ", 
      Button["Unset All Docked", RemoveDocked["Nuclear"], 
       bops[White, Darker@Red]]}]]], ops, CellID -> 333, 
  CellTags -> "nuk"];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {txt, but, nuk}]
```

Below are my tests for finding `DockedCells` (first three in lists) with `Cells`and `NotebookFind`. I used `Input` cells (last three in lists) as my experimental controls.

```
(* DockedCells return an enpty List {} or $Failed *)
(* Input Cells (last 3 in tags and ids) return a CellObject *)

ClearAll[tags, ids]
tags = {"txt", "but", "nuk", "cases1", "cases2", "del"};
ids = {111, 222, 333, 100, 200, 321};

(* with Cells *)
Echo[Cells[CellTags -> #] & /@ tags, "Cells by CellTags \[Rule] "];
Echo[Cells[CellID -> #] & /@ ids, "Cells by CellID \[Rule] "];

(* with NotebookFind *)
Echo[NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], #, All, CellTags, 
     IgnoreCase -> True, WrapAround -> True] & /@ tags, 
  "NotebookFind by CellTags \[Rule] "];
Echo[NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], #, All, CellID, 
     IgnoreCase -> True, WrapAround -> True] & /@ ids, 
  "NotebookFind by CellID \[Rule] "];
```

Comment: This is not a bug. The way to manipulate the content is via the DockedCells option on the notebook.

Comment: @ihojnicki Actually, it is possible to manipulate `DockedCells` also via the corresponding `CellObject`s, what can be more convenient in some cases. It is sad that there is no simple way to get these `CellObject`s. I hope it will be added in the future.

Comment: @ihojnicki please show me how to do that programmatically

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, adding a `DockedCells` option to `Cells` was considered when `AttachedCells` was added.  I wouldn't hold out hope for it.  @Jules Manson, removing a particular `Cell` from the `DockedCells` it is just a matter of list manipulation.  Assuming it was programmatically added to the notebook in the first place.

Comment: @ihojnicki It is sad, because changing the DockedCells option works surprisingly slowly as compared to manipulating CellObject.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, you can manipulate your `CellObject` all you want.  Whatever you do will never be reflected back into the option though, which is simply a consequence of the design.

Comment: @ihojnicki Yes, thank you. :) But at first I have to get the `CellObject`. And it is a bit tricky in the case of `DockedCells`, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Sure, but `EvaluationCell[]` is the only robust way to do it.  Otherwise, you are creating something that depends on initial preconditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: a straighforward solution

One could use the `Initialization` option of `Cell` to collect the required information:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> {Cell["DockedCell", "DockedCell", 
    Initialization :> 
     If[Head[$DockedCells] === List, $DockedCells = 
       Append[Select[$DockedCells, CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &], 
        EvaluationCell[]], $DockedCells = {EvaluationCell[]}]]}]
```

Instead of modifying `DockedCells` themself, one can change the default style for them with the same effect:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["DockedCell"], 
     Initialization :> 
      If[Head[$DockedCells] === List, $DockedCells = 
        Append[Select[$DockedCells, CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &], 
         EvaluationCell[]], $DockedCells = {EvaluationCell[]}]]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Now `$DockedCells` returns the complete list of `DockedCells`' handles:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  DockedCells -> {Cell["DockedCell_1", "DockedCell"], Cell["DockedCell_2", "DockedCell"], 
    Cell["DockedCell_3", "DockedCell"]}];

$DockedCells
First@NotebookRead[#] & /@ $DockedCells
```

> [image: screenshot]

> ```
> {"DockedCell_3", "DockedCell_2", "DockedCell_1"}
> ```

(I'm not sure why the list is reversed.)

With this approach it is easy to find a docked cell by its `CellID` or `CellTags`, for example:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  DockedCells -> {Cell["DockedCell_1", "DockedCell", CellTags -> "1"], 
    Cell["DockedCell_2", "DockedCell", CellTags -> "2"], 
    Cell["DockedCell_3", "DockedCell", CellTags -> "3"]}];

Select[$DockedCells, CurrentValue[#, CellTags] == "1" &]
```

> [image: output]

---

### Original answer

Since `DockedCells` support `Dynamic`, you can use `EvaluationBox[]` and `EvaluationCell[]` to get the handle. For example:

```
CreateWindow[
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData@
    ToBoxes@Button["my box", 
      NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
       Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@EvaluationCell[], "Input"]]], "DockedCell"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

One could also use the `DynamicWrapper` trick as in the [`ResourceFunction["PrintAsCellObject"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PrintAsCellObject):

```
CreateWindow[DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@DynamicWrapper["DockedCell",
                                       cell = EvaluationCell[ ],
                                       SingleEvaluation -> True,
                                       DestroyAfterEvaluation -> True
                       ], "DockedCell"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Additional note**

Cells created using `AttachCell` can only be found by `Cells` when the option `AttachedCell -> True` is specified, but this option is introduced only in version 13.0 (while `AttachCell` is introduced in 12.2). At the same time, `AttachCell` always return a `CellObject` corresponding to the cell created. Therefore, I would count the fact that `Cells` doesn't return the `DockedCells` as a missing functionality, and not a bug.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but targeting `Cells` by their textual content is not very practical. If you don't mind can you show me how to target individual docked `CellObject`-s by `CellID` or `CellTags`?

Comment: @JulesManson I've added an example on the bottom of the "Update" section.

Comment: This is the best solution so far. I tested it and it all works. Just one minor detail though. I have about a dozen custom cells "Style Definitions" created for my `Stylesheet` and the new `DockedCell` stylesheet cell erased them all only leaving behind `Default.nb` and `DockedCell`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JulesManson Yes, you can combine all style definitions in one custom stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Your advice on saving `StyleSheet` easily  recovers entire contents. I also "accepted" your answer. :)

Comment: As a side note to everyone. This is going to be a `ResourceFunction` therefore asking anyone to rethink how they design their `DockedCells` isn't practical. But I think adding a `DockedCell` `Style` cell to `StyleSheet` is practical considering there is no direct functionality for targeting `DockedCells`. Thank you all for your input especially to Alexey Popkov. It really helped.

Comment: @JulesManson After testing I think it is more robust to use `CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &` as a test for validity of a `CellObject`, instead of ``Developer`CellInformation[#] =!= $Failed &``. Changed the answer accordingly. Thanks for the Accept.

Comment: Yes I'm going with that style definition from your answer. I'm going to add functionality for adding that `DockedCell` style with a default `Safe ->True` `Option` for adding it by creating a new `NotebookDocument` which automatically opens to `Edit Stylesheet` for copying the `DockedCell` cell style over to the original `Notebook`.  Else with `Safe ->False` it would simply auto-generate it within the original `Notebook`. This way it doesn't erase anyone's private styles and I don't get a bad reputation for publishing careless `ResourceFunction`-s. This would only be done once per `Notebook`.

Comment: Since this is going to be written for a wider audience, can you modify the style definition `CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &` so that it would work for both `CellID` and `CellTags` this way there is a little more flexibility for the end-user?

Comment: @JulesManson The test `CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &` is not a test for the presence of the `CellID` option (`CurrentValue` returns some default value when this option isn't set), it checks for the validity of a `CellObject`. In this sense it is absolutely equivalent to `CurrentValue[#, CellTags] =!= $Failed &` which just a bit longer to type. You can use any of them with the same effect. ``Developer`CellInformation`` has a drawback that it returns unevaluated for some inputs, and as a consequence the test ``Developer`CellInformation[#] =!= $Failed &`` can give false `True`.

Comment: @JulesManson It looks like you are goaing the hard way adding the `"DockedCell"` cell style to the pivate stylesheet. It could be done much easier just by manipulatin the option  `StyleDefinitions` (simply append the new `Cell` to the list of `Cell`s in the `Notebook` expression). If you aren't sure how it can be done, please open new question and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: @JulesManson You can use [`ResourceFunction["AddStyleToNotebook"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddStyleToNotebook) to add a new style to Notebook's private stylesheet.

Comment: I did notice that a non-set `CellID` returns 0. By the way I posted a new question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272177/how-can-a-cell-be-appended-to-the-list-of-cells-in-the-notebook-expression

Comment: thank you again :)