# How can a Style Cell be safely programmatically appended to the Notebook Stylesheet at (Format -> Edit -> Stylesheet)

Tags: programming, notebooks, stylesheet, user-interface, docked-cell

The purpose of this is to append a `DockedCell` style definition to the list of cells inside `Edit Stylesheet` without deleting any existing style cells. My one attempt tends to erase existing private or custom style cells. More information can be found here: [Cannot find DockedCells with Cells or NotebookFind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272033/cannot-find-dockedcells-with-cells-or-notebookfind/272038?noredirect=1#comment679627_272038)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`ResourceFunction["AddStyleToNotebook"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddStyleToNotebook) which allows to add a new style to the private stylesheet without erasing the existing styles. But unfortunately currently it has a bug specifically with the `Initialization` option. Hence until the bug isn't fixed we can define our own `AddStyleToNotebook`:

```
AddStyleToNotebook[nb_NotebookObject, cell_Cell] := 
 Module[{oldDefs = CurrentValue[nb, StyleDefinitions], newDefs},
  newDefs = If[Head[oldDefs] === Notebook,
    If[FreeQ[First@oldDefs, cell, {1}], Insert[oldDefs, cell, {1, -1}], oldDefs],
    Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> oldDefs]], cell}, 
     StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]];
  SetOptions[nb, StyleDefinitions -> newDefs]]
```

Use it as follows:

```
AddStyleToNotebook[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell[StyleData["DockedCell"], 
  Initialization :> 
   If[Head[System`$DockedCells] === List, 
    System`$DockedCells = 
     Append[Select[System`$DockedCells, CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &], 
      EvaluationCell[]], System`$DockedCells = {EvaluationCell[]}]]]
```

(Here I put `$DockedCells` in the `` System` ``  context in order to avoid namespace conflicts.)

---

**My report about the bug in the current `ResourceFunction["AddStyleToNotebook"]`**

Here, I'm including the report I just submitted using the "Submit a message about this function" button on the function's [page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddStyleToNotebook):

> Currently the resource function `AddStyleToNotebook` has a bug: when we try to add several times a new style containing the `Initialization` option, the latter will be damaged. As an example, consider the following use case:
>
> ```
> ResourceFunction["AddStyleToNotebook"][EvaluationNotebook[], 
>   "DockedCell", {Initialization :> 
>     If[Head[System`$DockedCells] === List, 
>      System`$DockedCells = 
>       Append[Select[System`$DockedCells, CurrentValue[#, CellID] =!= $Failed &], 
>        EvaluationCell[]], System`$DockedCells = {EvaluationCell[]}]}];
> ```
>
> If we evaluate the above several times, we get a list of the above values as the value for the `Initialization` option, what is wrong and leads to the wrong behavior. The above definition is taken from the following answer where its purpose is explained:
>
> https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272038/280
>
> Sincerely,
> Alexey Popkov

Comment: thank you for this. you've been very helpful.

Comment: I have just one more question. How do I make certain it only adds the style once in a given notebook? I know I can easily add a default `Option` `setstyle -> False` which must be set to `setstyle -> True` the first time it is run but can this be automated?

Comment: @JulesManson Please look closer at the defintion for `AddStyleToNotebook`. It already includes a checkup for the presence of the `cell` via `FreeQ[First@oldDefs, cell, {1}]`.

Comment: you might be pleased to know that i sent a feature request to Wolfram for a direct way for finding `DockedCells` through the `Technical Support (for Service Subscribers)`.

Comment: @JulesManson Thank you.